# Publishing spring application to tomcat server showing file not found in Eclipse STS

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I  have a spring project. I have 3 modules ui, sql and sevice in the project.

Versions of user tools and frameworks are given below

- Tomcat Version    -    8.5
- Spring Tool Suite -    3.9.4
- Java              -    8
- Maven             -    3.9

WAR file is created for service module. Other modules are integrated to it.
I build the spring application with maven "mvn clean install".
When i started tomcat server after adding the war file created by the build. 
It is showing following error

> 'Publishing to Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost...' has encountered a
>   problem.
>
> Publishing failed with multiple errors
>
> File not found:
>   ProjectLocation\services\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven\com.company\services\pom.properties. File not found:
>   ProjectLocation\services\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources\META-INF\maven\com.company\services\pom.xml.

Please help me to find the problem with this.

Comment: I don't know if that happened when you wrote your question but there is a typo at the end: \com.compnay\

Comment: Yes that is added by mistake. I corrected it